# FF return 0 as Adobe Flash Player version, while Flash has been installed in system

Tags: flash, firefox, swfobject

I'm trying to make site more user-friendly and in case if user doesn't have Flash Player or has old version I want to show special message.

For getting Flash version I use [swfobject.js library](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). In IE and Chrome it works fine, in FF it always return 0 as version major number (before installing of Flash Player and after).

```
 if(typeof swfobject !== 'undefined') {
        alert(swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion().major);
 }
```

I thought once you install Flash Player in the system, all browser automatically should be notified of it and be able to use it. Or Firefox need some special plugin? How to check if video could be played in FF?

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `swfobject.registerObject(...)` in head tag?

More info about this function:

https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api